# Android Observable/AsyncTask waiting till loop ends before executing

Tags: java, android

I'm reading lines of text from an input stream (currently a text file, eventually via bluetooth)

The lines are being wrapped in a bufferItem and added to a buffer (ArrayList) which is Observable & triggers

```
setChanged();
notifyObservers(item);
```

The update method on the Observer fires off an AsyncTask for each buffer item.

Because my input stream will be essentially 'endless', what I want is for all this to happen concurrently (ie data being processed while new data also arriving in real time), but what I'm finding is that the asyncTasks don't kick off until the entire file has been read.

The file reading bit is below:

```
while (((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)) {

    if (inputLine.substring(0,1).equals("$")){
    bufferItem bi = new bufferItem();
    bi.addItem(inputLine);
        for (int i = 1; i < repeatRate; i++) {
            bi.addItem(bufferedReader.readLine());
        }
    // adding to buffer triggers the observer
    buffer.addItem(bi);
    }
}
```

The whole Observable/Observer process is working, but none of the downstream processes kick in until after the entire input file has been read.

I'm monitoring it using lines similar to:

```
System.out.println("Item added to buffer");
```

With a println at the point where an item is added to the buffer and another in one of the downstream processes within an asyncTask

So I'm getting all the 'Item added to buffer' lines first, followed by the downstream process log lines, when I would be expecting them to be interspersed.

So the question is (I think) - why does it wait until the loop has completed before acting on the notifyObservers() instructions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is related to how Honeycomb (and later) handle AsyncTask - by putting AsyncTasks on the same thread, and is not related to the Observer pattern as I first thought.

To get it working, I moved the file reading code to a separate AsyncTask and called it like this:

```
task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

This allows the AsyncTasks that process the file data to kick off immediately.

If they, in turn are called in the 'standard' way

```
new Task(param1, param2).execute();
```

then they will run in sequence.

They can also be called thus:

```
new Task(param1, param2).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

in which case they will also run in parallel, but not in the order in which the data is coming off the file being read. This is important if you need to package the file data using the same order as it comes out of the file.

This article was the key:

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/android-asynctask-behavior-changes-you-should-know/

Also, the Android doc - scroll down to Order of Execution

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the sequence of data packets/lines does matters, so:

1. A receiver thread to read input in chunks, add those to an input buffer Queue.
2. A processor thread to peek() the input queue, process items and place them to an output buffer queue. If input queue is empty, this thread waits for receiver to put something on queue and notify it.
3. Finally, a dispatcher thread to send/write/save/etc the processed items off the output buffer queue. If output queue is empty, this thread waits for processor to put something on queue and notify it.

You'd need to have an upper limit on buffer queues, so they block when full, else you may run out of RAM. Also ensure the flow is not blocked due to any of the threads error out.